# Applying 'Uncle Bob's Clean Code' on this small exercice

Tags: c#

I'm trying to apply Uncle Bob's Clean Code practices onto this exercise I'm helping someone with.
(The exercise assignment is in a "docstring" comment above the `Main`.)

I'm unsure what the best naming convention would be for `ReturnAllCombinationsOfInputtedList`, although I suspect it doesn't involve the return word in it's name for starters.
Same for `CreateArray1to30()`. Any suggestions for name choices/proper conventions here?

Do you guys see anything else that I should've done differently in your opinion?

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleAppHelpingAlexWithExercices
{
    class Program
    {
        //**************************************************************************
        // How many different exam tickets with two different questions can be made, 
        // from a syllabus with 30 questions
        //**************************************************************************
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] questionsList = CreateArray1to30();
            List<string> combinations = ReturnAllCombinationsOfInputtedList(questionsList);
            int amountOfUniqueCombinations = combinations.Distinct<string>().Count();
            Console.WriteLine("Total unique combinations: {0}", amountOfUniqueCombinations);
        }

        static List<string> ReturnAllCombinationsOfInputtedList(int[] questionsList)
        {
            List<string> combinations = new List<string>();
            int[] aTest = new int[2];
            foreach (int firstQuestion in questionsList)
            {
                foreach (int secondQuestion in questionsList)
                {
                    if (firstQuestion != secondQuestion)
                    {
                        aTest[0] = firstQuestion;
                        aTest[1] = secondQuestion;
                        //Makes AB and BA tests both AB, so we can de-duplicate later.
                        Array.Sort(aTest);
                        combinations.Add(String.Format("{0}&{1}", aTest[0], aTest[1]));
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} and {1}", aTest[0], aTest[1]);
                    }
                }
            }
            return combinations;
        }

        static int[] CreateArray1to30()
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 30).ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! We need to know *what the code is intended to achieve*. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question, including a title that summarises the *purpose* of the code. We want to know **why** much more than **how**. The more you tell us about [what your code is for](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1226), the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  The title needs an [edit] to simply [**state the task**](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2436), rather than your concerns about the code.

Comment: I'm not a c# programmer so won't go into any detail, but surely you don't need to make all permutations and de-duplicate them?
If you have 30 questions, you have a choice of 29 to combine with the first, but only 28 to combine with the second and so on...

Answer (score 3):

- `CreateArray1to30()` could be renamed to `CreateQuestions()`
- `ReturnAllCombinationsOfInputtedList()` could be renamed to `Combinations()` or `QuestionCombinations()`
- `ReturnAllCombinationsOfInputtedList()` does too much. The call to `.Distinct()` is unecessary, and can be replaced with correct indices in the first place. Furthermore, the `aTest` array is entirely useless and could be replaced by using `firstQuestion` and `secondQuestion` directly.
- Strings are a non ideal data structures for the exams, as you use a different format when printing them out

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


namespace ConsoleAppHelpingAlexWithExercices
{
    struct ExamTicket {
        public int Question1, Question2;
        public ExamTicket(int Question1, int Question2) {
            this.Question1 = Question1;
            this.Question2 = Question2;
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        //**************************************************************************
        // How many different exam tickets with two different questions can be made, 
        // from a syllabus with 30 questions
        //**************************************************************************
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] questions = CreateQuestions();
            var combinations = new List<ExamTicket>(Combinations(questions));
            foreach (var combination in combinations) {
                Console.WriteLine($"{combination.Question1} and {combination.Question2}");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Total unique combinations: {0}", combinations.Count);
        }

        static IEnumerable<ExamTicket> Combinations(int[] questions)
        {
            for (int i=0;i<questions.Length;++i) {
                for (int j=i+1;j<questions.Length;++j) {
                    yield return new ExamTicket(questions[i],questions[j]);
                }
            }
        }

        static int[] CreateQuestions()
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 30).ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `static IEnumerable<ExamTicket> ToExam(this int[] questions)` :)